# element not interactable on Amazon.com

Tags: python, xpath, automation, robotframework, software-quality

I'm doing a very simple test for an interview and I can't click the "Start here" link, the error is  `element not interactable`

Here is the following code:

`Click Link     xpath=//a[contains(text(),'Comece aqui.')]`

Its a pretty straightforward element but still I cannot interact, inspecting the element I have:

`<a href="https://www.amazon.com.br/ap/register?openid.pape.max_auth_age=0&amp;openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com.br%2F%3F_encoding%3DUTF8%26ref_%3Dnav_newcust&amp;openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&amp;openid.assoc_handle=brflex&amp;openid.mode=checkid_setup&amp;openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&amp;openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&amp;" rel="nofollow" class="nav-a">Comece aqui.</a>`

Any guesses?

Edit: here is my entire test

````
Library  SeleniumLibrary

** Variables **
${click_criarconta}     //a[contains(text(),'Comece aqui.')]
${name}             ap_customer_name
${email}            ap_email
${senha}            ap_password
${senha2}           ap_password_check

** Keywords **
Abrir Site
    Open Browser    https://www.amazon.com.br/  chrome

Botão para criar conta
    Sleep     2s
    Click Link    xpath=${click_criarconta}
Inserir nome
    Input Text      ${name}     Name Surname
Inserir e-mail
    Input Text      ${email}    name@outlook.com
Inserir senha
    Input Password  ${senha}    12345
    Input Password  ${senha2}   12345

Fechar Browser
  Close Browser

** Test Cases **
Cenário 1: Acessing Amazon and creating a new account
    Abrir Site
    Botão para criar conta
    Inserir nome
    Inserir e-mail
    Inserir senha
    Fechar Browser```

Here is the element
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OJjw.png
````

Comment: We can't help because of several issues: You need to share all your existing Selenium code including a link to the page you trying to work on and since you never accepting given you answers

Comment: Didn't understand what you say by "since you never accepting given you answers" but the URL is http://www.amazon.com.br and then starting a new account, the similar in US-amazon is the "Start here" link

Comment: Can you share an screenshot of the element you want?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OJjw.png

Comment: @jaimejunior You do understand now as I see. Please keep doing so in a future, this may help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a couple of elements very similar in the page.

**The first one:**

[image]

You can find it with this xpath:

```
(//a[text()='Comece aqui.'])[1]
```

**The second one**

[image]

You can find it with this xpath:

```
(//a[text()='Comece aqui.'])[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

`(//a[text()='Comece aqui.'])[2]`

That one worked perfectly, thanks Jaky